# Null case with concatenation

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I have the below situation in my project:

@num1 is an integer

1. when @num1 = null/' ' then output should be space(0)
2. else if it is single digit, concatenate with '0' in the front. If double digit, show as it is.

Example:

```
1. @num1 = null/'' output: space(0)
2. @num1 = '0' output:00
3. @num1 = '9' output:09
4. @num1 = '11' output = 11
```

My code:

```
declare @num1 int = null
select @num1,
CASE
    WHEN cast(@num1 as varchar) = null THEN space(0)
    ELSE RIGHT(CONCAT('00', CONVERT(VARCHAR,@num1)),2)
END as 'output'
```

This code works fine for examples 2,3,4. But when I set @num1 = null, the output still shows as '00'. desired output should be space(0)/space. Missing some conversion here. Any help?

Comment: `@num1` is an *int*. Talking about it containing an *empty string* is nonsense. You cannot *store* an empty string in an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something simple I noticed and fixed. There is no need to casting at all.

```
declare @num1 int = null
select @num1,
CASE
    WHEN @num1 is null THEN space(0)
    ELSE RIGHT(CONCAT('00', CONVERT(VARCHAR,@num1)),2)
END as 'output'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you `cast` ??

You can do :

```
. . .
WHEN @num1 is null THEN space(1)
```

So, you can also simplify it as :

```
SELECT @num1, (CASE WHEN @num1 is not null 
                    THEN RIGHT(CONCAT('00', CONVERT(VARCHAR,@num1)),2) 
                    ELSE space(1)
                END) as 'output'
```

Comment: oops. Yeah I was doing something like @num1 = null and it was still throwing '00'. Didn't realize that. Thanks!